# Java File Not Found Exception Error

Tags: java, file, jasper-reports

I am trying to view a Jasper Report.

I keep getting the error "java io file not found exception". Is there a syntax that I am missing in the file name. Or is there something I am doing wrong. Please find a snippet of the code below.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {

        String report = "‪‪C:\\Users\\Victory\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Supermarket29April15\\src\\reports\\report4.jrxml";
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, con);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

    System.out.println(new File(report).getAbsoluteFile());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why  you have "\\"  in below path. ‪‪C:\\Users\\Victory\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Supermarket29April15\\src\\reports\\report4.jrxml

Comment: hope you have file at this loction ‪‪C:\\Users\\Victory\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Supermarket29April15\\src\\reports\\report4.jrxml  and share the full stack-trace of error logs. and check the proper path and check if you are not doing any typo in path

Comment: @shiprad yes I do have the file at the location

Comment: @Janny It would be illegal to use one \ as it would be an escape character in java. Thats the error I get: Illegal escape charcter. Or am I missing it somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try using only the / and not the //.

and check file permissions.

Comment: is it a full answer?

Comment: @ AFR I still get the file not found exception. Is there a library I am to use to access local files. Or is it because the file is in my project folder. I am using netbeans to run this.

Comment: Can u copy the file into your project folder? If u can, try and then tell us.

@manetsus and yes is a full answer. I think he needs a solution por the I/O exception, not an explanation of the exception.

Comment: @AFR The file is already in the project src folder, I am asking: Is it because the file is in the project folder that I am getting the error when I run the project.

Comment: Forward slashes are used on Unix, but the path the OP uses a Windows path, hence backslashes are correct. He also correctly escapes them.

Comment: @OkoyeVictory ok why are you using the long route and not the name of the instead? Put the file inot the project execution folder. Check permissions.